# Google Charts & PHP / CSV

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv, charts

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['URL', 'total visits'],
<?php foreach ($tag as $key => $value){ ?>['<?php echo $key; ?>', '<?php echo      $value; ?>']<?php echo ", \r\n"; ?><?php } ?>

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Traffic by Page',
      legend: 'none',
      pieSliceText: 'label',
      slices: {  1: {offset: 0.2},
                2: {offset: 0.3},
                3: {offset: 0.4},
                4: {offset: 0.5},
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

This is a google charts piechart example.  The data is from a csv file which all of the front end pages write to.  I then sort the data into an array which i call $tag.  And with php i parse so that they can output the correct format.

When I view source from the loaded page, everything looks perfect (to me, just like the charts example downloaded from google) in the code as like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['URL', 'total visits'],
['https://www.jason.com/ ', '4'], 
['https://jason.com/ ', '63'], 
['https://jason.com/latitude-longitude-tool/ ', '7'], 
['https://jason.com/login/signup/ ', '1'], 
['https://jason.com/login/ ', '10'], 
['https://jason.com/accounts/contact.php ', '3'], 
['https://jason.com/accounts/myip.php ', '1'], 
['https://jason.com/accounts/domainsearch.php ', '1'], 
['https://jason.com/whois/ ', '1'], 
['https://jason.com/robots.txt ', '2'], 
['https://jason.com/accounts/ ', '5'], 
['https://jason.com/js/main.js ', '1'], 
['https://jason.com/account ', '1'], 

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Traffic by Page',
      legend: 'none',
      pieSliceText: 'label',
      slices: {  1: {offset: 0.2},
                2: {offset: 0.3},
                3: {offset: 0.4},
                4: {offset: 0.5},
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Yet this is the visual output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4fcK.jpg)

Please help:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the single quotes around the values. For example it should be `['https://www.jason.com/ ', 4]` not `['https://www.jason.com/ ', '4']`

Change your PHP to remove the single quotes around the point where you output the value:

```
['<?php echo $key; ?>', <?php echo $value; ?>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['URL', 'total visits'],
['https://www.jason.com/ ', 4],
['https://jason.com/ ', 63],
['https://jason.com/latitude-longitude-tool/ ', 7],
['https://jason.com/login/signup/ ', 1],
['https://jason.com/login/ ', 10],
['https://jason.com/accounts/contact.php ', 3],
['https://jason.com/accounts/myip.php ', 1],
['https://jason.com/accounts/domainsearch.php ', 1],
['https://jason.com/whois/ ', 1],
['https://jason.com/robots.txt ', 2],
['https://jason.com/accounts/ ', 5],
['https://jason.com/js/main.js ', 1],
['https://jason.com/account ', 1],
    ], false);

    var options = {
      title: 'Traffic by Page',
      legend: 'none',
      pieSliceText: 'label',
      slices: {  1: {offset: 0.2},
                2: {offset: 0.3},
                3: {offset: 0.4},
                4: {offset: 0.5},
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  Ella fixed it!